# virsh console hangs when i connect kvm VM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu, opensuse, virsh

**KVM Host Environment:-**

```
# cat /etc/issue
Welcome to openSUSE 13.2 "Harlequin" - Kernel \r (\l).

# /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 2.1.3
```

Running VMs list as follows,

```
# virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 4     vm10                         running
 5     vm-test                      running
 6     vm11                         running
 16    vm12                         running
 18    vm1                          running
```

When i tried to connect `vm1` console session using below command. after pressing enter key, no response.

```
# virsh console vm1
Connected to domain vm1
Escape character is ^]
```

```
# cat /var/log/libvirt/qemu/vm1.log

2022-07-10 06:11:09.972+0000: starting up
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none /usr/bin/qemu-kvm -name vm1 -S -machine pc-i440fx-2.1,accel=kvm,usb=off -cpu host -m 32768 -realtime mlock=off -smp 4,sockets=4,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid 25da0d89-4249-41ae-baab-5282d1531ef7 -nographic -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/vm1.monitor,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc -no-shutdown -boot strict=on -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1.0x2 -drive file=/srv/vm1.img,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=raw,cache=none,aio=native -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 -drive file=/srv/vm1-data.img,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk4,format=raw,cache=none,aio=native -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0xb,drive=drive-virtio-disk4,id=virtio-disk4 -drive if=none,id=drive-ide0-1-0,readonly=on,format=raw -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-1-0,id=ide0-1-0 -netdev tap,fd=22,id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=23 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:2d:83:a1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5 -msg timestamp=on
Domain id=2 is tainted: host-cpu
char device redirected to /dev/pts/1 (label charserial0)
```

So, it looks that `vm1` is running fine. And there is nothing wrong in logs as well. But it doesn't accept expect `Ctrl + 5` keys.

IP of `vm1` able to ping from KVM host & other machines, Also ssh connection from KVM host & other machines it says below errors.

```
# ssh root@vm1
ssh: connect to host vm1 port 22: Connection refused
```

Please let me know what could the problem with `virsh console vm1` connection?

Answer (score 2):

`virsh console` opens a connection to the guest's primary serial port. This will only show any output / accept input, if there is something in the guest OS attached to the other end of the serial port (ie a getty process). IOW, it hasn't hung, there just isn't anything in your guest using the serial port to respond to.

OS using systemd would normally automatically spawn a getty process, if there is no graphical console available (ie no VGA device). If you do have a graphical console configured, then try connecting to that instead. You don't say how you've configured it, but typically you'd use VNC/SPICE clients to connect to a graphical console, such as `virt-viewer vm1`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a debian user (may be different for you)

1. ssh root@vm1 is impossible until I edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config (permitRootLogin yes) ...try your non-root user?
2. virsh console vm hangs  : systemctl enable (|start)  serial-getty@ttyS0.service ... fortunatley (for me) a "virt-manager" console (VNC or spice) was OK (and mandatory because of unconfigured network/ no ssh) ;-)
   Phil